# Mount usb in media subfolder as default

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

Whenever I mount a hard drive or USB by clicking on it on the Unity bar (or from the file browser). It appears in a folder in `/media` with my username (ang example would be `/media/$USER/usb_memory_flash` if the USB flash driver was named `usb_memory_flash`). Is there a way that this does not happen and it the hdd/usb is mounted in `/media` directly (I would like it to go to `/media/usb_memory_flash`)? Obviously I can mount the USB flash drive or hard drive using `sudo mount`and place it wherever I want, but this is not the solution that I am looking for.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One simple step

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/personal-udisks2.rules
```

and then type into there (or copy-paste)

```
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
```

Be aware that the removable media will now be shared with all users on the system - which in my case was desirable, but not necessarily in yours.